# Using dirname with img src to display a logo on apache webserver

Tags: php, html, css, image, src

So here is the structure of my basic practice website

```
/opt
    /lampp
        /htdocs
            /web
                /img
                    logo.png
                /tests
                    HomeView_test.php
                /view
                    HomeView.class.php
                index.php
```

My initial problem was that I am using auto loading and running HomeView.class.php from index.php and HomeView.class.php from HomeView_test.php would not load my logo image on both if I only hard coded the path from one. So for example if I hard coded the path to work when called from index.php it would not also work when called from HomeView_test.php

Here is what is in HomeView.class.php

```
<?php
class HomeView {
  public static function show() {  
    $pathDir = dirname(__FILE__);
    $fileName = $pathDir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . "../img/logo.png";
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8"/>
        <title>Website</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <header>
            <img src="<?php echo $fileName;?>" alt="Logo" width="150" height="100"/>
            <nav>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">About</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Contact Us</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </header>
        <footer>
            <p>
                &copy 2015 Peeps, Inc. All Rights Reserved.
            </p>
        </footer>
    </body>
</html>
<?php
  }
}
?>
```

I thought that the the php echo of the path inside the src would work but it is still not loading the logo image.

Hard coding in img/logo.png only works when in index.php it calls HomeView.class.php but when I call it from HomeView_test.php it needs ../img/logo.png to show the logo

Does anyone have any idea as to what I am doing wrong? Maybe the img src and php syntax is off since I've never tried using php in conjunction with img src before.

Comment: First off, I'd suggest looking into how to properly (or rather better) use OOP, second, for images to appear in browser, you want the path to the image from the document root (set up in your webserver vhost) not your file system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, when you want to show an image from a web page, regardless of what backend language you are using, you need to provide the public server path to the media.

So when you have this statement:

```
<img src="<?php echo $fileName;?>" alt="Logo" width="150" height="100"/>
```

The variable `$filename` ought to look something like `/img/logo.png` when outputted in HTML.

Your goal is to provide the public web location of the url, not the server location.

Comment: img/logo.png only works when in index.php it calls HomeView.class.php but when I call it from HomeView_test.php it needs ../img/logo.png to show the logo

Comment: Notice I put an absolute path to the image relative to the web server `/img/logo.png`